# Unwanted text on first page

Tags: color, svg, transparent

I am trying to load svg images into my latex document. I tried using the svg package with `\usepackag{svg}` and I tried including pdf_tex files from inkscape using `\usepackage{color} \usepackage{transparent} \graphicspath{{folderwithmyimages/}}`. Both ways work for loading the svg images but with both I get a first page before my title page which contains only the following text:

[image]

Does anybody know whats causing this or has a tip on how to remove the first page in a latex document? I googled this text and it seems to be related to the transparent package but I have no clue how to solve it.

Edit: After changing position of `\usepackage{svg}` to the first usepackage command in my document and restarting my latex editor the problem is gone.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a short example code that reproduces the problem. Without this, it will probably be very difficult for anyone to help you.